# IOS How to retrieve one of the element in xml after calling success and put it into an array to display on tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, soap, nsxmlparser

.M file, This is where i authenticate my self sign cert and retrieve it using nsurl connection and parse to nsxmlparser before putting them to tableview. But i can receive the data but can retrieve the specific element that has the name "Severity". Please help.!! i need to load the items in Severity tag into an array and insert into a table view.

```
//  IncidentTableViewController.m

#import "IncidentTableViewController.h"

#import "InviteViewController.h"
#import "Incidents.h"
#import "FeedListMenuView.h"
#import "FeedListMenuView.h"
#import "FeedViewController.h"


@interface IncidentTableViewController ()
@property NSString *currentElement;
@property NSMutableData *webResponseData;
@property NSMutableDictionary *dictBook;
@property NSMutableArray *arrBook;
@property NSMutableString *elementValue;


@end
@interface FeedViewController ()

@end

@implementation IncidentTableViewController

//@synthesize response;
//@synthesize status;
@synthesize resultLabel;
@synthesize  webResponseData, currentElement;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Response recieved");
    output= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//    NSString *severity = @"Informational";
    NSString *soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                            " <IncidentGetList xmlns=\"https://www.monitoredsecurity.com/\">"
                             "<Severity></Severity>"
                             "<SourceOrganization></SourceOrganization>"
                             "<DestinationOrganization></DestinationOrganization>"
                            "<MaxIncidents></MaxIncidents>"
                             "<SourceIP></SourceIP>"
                             "<Category></Category>"
                             "<ExcludeCategory></ExcludeCategory>"
                             "<StartTimeStampGMT></StartTimeStampGMT>"
                             "<EndTimeStampGMT></EndTimeStampGMT>"
                             "<CustomerSeverity></CustomerSeverity>"
                             "</IncidentGetList>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>";


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.monitoredsecurity.com/SWS/incidents.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"https://www.monitoredsecurity.com/IncidentGetList" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];







    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    [connection start];

    if(connection)
    {
        webResponseData = [NSMutableData data] ;

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection is NULL");
    }

       // Menu View



    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    // Insert Navigation Bar
//    [self insertNavBarWithScreenName:SCREEN_INCIDENT];
//    
//    CGRect frm = btnDownArrow.frame;
//    frm.origin.x = 185;
//    frm.origin.y = 42;
//    [btnDownArrow setFrame:frm];
//    [self.navBarView addSubview:btnDownArrow];
//    
//   
//    
//    [self addGestureRecognizersToPiece:self.view];
}

- (void)addGestureRecognizersToPiece:(UIView *)piece
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapPiece:)];
    tapGesture.delegate = self;
    [piece addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (void) tapPiece:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    [btnDownArrow setSelected:NO];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
//
//- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
//#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
//    return 1;
//}
//
//- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
//    return [output countc];
//}


#pragma mark --
#pragma mark -- Set navigationBar --

- (void) didClickNavBarLeftButton
{
    CGRect frm = self.view.frame;
    frm.origin.x = 254;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [self.view setFrame:frm];
    //[self setEnable:NO];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self tapPiece:nil];
}


- (void) didClickNavBarRightButton
{
    [self tapPiece:nil];

    if (rightController == nil) {
        rightController = [[InviteViewController alloc] viewFromStoryboard];
        [self.view.superview addSubview:rightController.view];
        [rightController.view setFrame:CGRectMake( 320, 0, gScreenSize.width, gScreenSize.height )];
    }

    [collectView setUserInteractionEnabled:!(self.view.frame.origin.x > -254)];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    if (self.view.frame.origin.x > -254) {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( -254 * 2, 0 );
        rightController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( -254, 0 );
    }
    else {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( -254, 0 );
        rightController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( 0, 0 );
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


#pragma mark --
#pragma mark -- UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate --

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[arrFeeds objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [arrFeeds count];
}





#pragma mark --
#pragma mark -- FeedListMenuViewDelegate --

- (void) didClickFeedListMenu:(FeedListMenuView *)flmv index:(int)index
{
    [btnDownArrow setSelected:NO];
}



- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Response recieved");
    [self.webResponseData  setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Data recieved");

   // NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self.webResponseData  appendData:data];



     // NSLog(responseString);
   // [response setText:responseString];

    //[status setText:@"Response retrieved async"];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"Received %lu Bytes", (unsigned long)[webResponseData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:
                        [webResponseData mutableBytes] length:[webResponseData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);

    //now parsing the xml

    NSData *myData = [theXML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:myData];

    //setting delegate of XML parser to self
    xmlParser.delegate = self;
    [xmlParser parse];

    // Run the parser
    @try{
        BOOL parsingResult = [xmlParser parse];
        NSLog(@"parsing result = %hhd",parsingResult);
    }
    @catch (NSException* exception)
    {
        UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Server Error" message:[exception reason] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
}


//Implement the NSXmlParserDelegate methods
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:
(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
  element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"SecurityIncidentSummary"]) {

        IncidentGetList    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        Severity   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    }    //NSLog(@"current element: ", elementName);
}
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    NSLog(@"File found and parsing started");

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"Severity"]) {
        [Severity appendString:string];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"SecurityIncidentSummary"]) {

        [IncidentGetList setObject:Severity forKey:@"Severity"];

        [feeds addObject:[IncidentGetList copy]];
    }

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

   NSLog(@"Final Feed : %@",feeds);
}




- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}
-       (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:
(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge

{
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0)
    {
        SecIdentityRef identity = [self getClientCertificate];
        CFArrayRef certs = [self getCertificate];
        NSArray *myArray = (__bridge NSArray *)certs;
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:identity
                                                                    certificates:myArray persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
    else {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}

-(CFArrayRef)getCertificate
{
    SecIdentityRef identity = [self getClientCertificate];
    SecCertificateRef certificate = nil;
    SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identity, &certificate);
    SecCertificateRef certs[1] = {certificate};
    CFArrayRef array = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **) certs, 1, NULL);
    SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
    SecTrustRef myTrust;

    OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(array, myPolicy, &myTrust);
    if (status == noErr){
        NSLog(@"No Err creating certificate");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Possible Err Creating certificate");
    }
    return array;
}
-(SecIdentityRef)getClientCertificate
{
    SecIdentityRef identityApp = nil;
    NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cert" ofType:@"p12"];
    NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
    CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (__bridge CFDataRef)PKCS12Data;
    CFStringRef password = CFSTR("123456");
    const void *keys[] = {kSecImportExportPassphrase}; //kSecImportExportPassphrase };
    const void *values[] = {password};
    CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);
    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, options, &items);
    CFRelease(options);
    CFRelease(password);
    if (securityError == errSecSuccess)
    {
        NSLog(@"Success opening p12 certificate. Items: %ld", CFArrayGetCount(items));
        CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
        identityApp = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict,
                                                           kSecImportItemIdentity);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Error opening Certificate.");
    }
    return identityApp;
}

//- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
//    NSError *error = nil;
//    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[@"SII_2350" stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[@"p12" pathExtension]];
//    NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path options:0 error:&error];
//    CFDataRef inP12data = (__bridge CFDataRef)certData;
//    SecIdentityRef identity;
//    SecTrustRef trust;
//    
//    
//    OSStatus status = extractIdentityAndTrust(inP12data, &identity, &trust);
//    NSLog(@"status %d", (int)status);
//    if(status == errSecSuccess) {
//        SecCertificateRef certificate;
//        SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identity, &certificate);
//        const void *certs[] = { certificate };
//        CFArrayRef certsArray = CFArrayCreate(NULL, certs, 1, NULL);
//        NSArray *certificatesForCredential = (__bridge NSArray *)certsArray;
//        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:identity
//                                                                 certificates:certificatesForCredential
//                                                                  persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
//        [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
//        CFRelease(identity);
//        CFRelease(certificate);
//        CFRelease(certsArray);
//    }
//    else {
//        [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
//    }
//    
//    
//}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Did recieve error: %@", [error localizedDescription]]);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [error userInfo]]);
}



OSStatus extractIdentityAndTrust(CFDataRef inPKCS12Data, SecIdentityRef *identity, SecTrustRef *trust){
//    OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;
//    
//    CFStringRef password = CFSTR("123456");
//    const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
//    const void *values[] = { password };
//    
//    CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);
//    
//    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
//    securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inP12data, options, &items);
//    
//    if (securityError == 0) {
//        CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
//        const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
//        tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemIdentity);
//        *identity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
//        const void *tempTrust = NULL;
//        tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemTrust);
//        *trust = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;
//    }
//    
//    if (options) {
//        CFRelease(options);
//    }
//    
//    return securityError;
    OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;
    CFStringRef password = CFSTR("123456");
    const void *keys[] =   { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
    const void *values[] = { password };
    CFDictionaryRef optionsDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(
                                                           NULL, keys,
                                                           values, 1,
                                                           NULL, NULL);
    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data,
                                    optionsDictionary,
                                    &items);

    if (securityError == 0) {
        CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex (items, 0);
        const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
        tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust,
                                             kSecImportItemIdentity);
        *identity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
        const void *tempTrust = NULL;
        tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue (myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemTrust);
        *trust = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;
    }

    if (optionsDictionary) {
        CFRelease(optionsDictionary);
    }

    return securityError;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)
    return [feeds count];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


static NSString *cellId = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellId];


    }

   cell.textLabel.text= [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Severity"];
    return cell;





}

//UNTIL HERE


//
//- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
////    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:<#@"reuseIdentifier"#> forIndexPath:indexPath];
//    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
//    
//    UITableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[cellIdentifier ];
//                         
//                         if(cell == nill){
//                             cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]autorelease];
//                         
//                         }
//
//                         
////    
////    return cell;
//}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

 //In a xib-based application, navigation from a table can be handled in -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
//- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//    // Navigation logic may go here, for example:
//    // Create the next view controller.
//   // <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:<#@"Nib name"#> bundle:nil];
//    
//    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
//    
//    // Push the view controller.
//    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
//    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
//
//}


/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomNavViewController.h"
#import "FeedListMenuView.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Security/Security.h>
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import "SYSoapTool.h"

@interface IncidentTableViewController :UIViewController< UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, SOAPToolDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIButton * btnDownArrow;

    IBOutlet UICollectionView * collectView;
      NSMutableArray * arrFeeds;

    SuperViewController * rightController;
    NSMutableArray *output;
    BOOL errorParsing;
    NSMutableString *strCaptured;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;




}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *datalist;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *status;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *response;
-(IBAction)retrieveResponseAsync:(id)sender;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace;

OSStatus extractIdentityAndTrust(CFDataRef inP12data, SecIdentityRef *identity, SecTrustRef *trust);



@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to retrieve Data Element By it's tag So For that you have to add the value of that tag Using NSDictonary And copy Dictonary to NSMutableArry So You will Get data  like in Json Formate. 
/* Here is my Code for Get RSS Feed */

```
@interface ViewController (){


NSMutableDictionary *IncidentGetList;
NSMutableString* Severity;
NSMutableArray *feeds;
NSString *element;
}


 /* Parser Delegate method */

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

element = elementName;

if ([element isEqualToString:@"IncidentGetList"]) {

    IncidentGetList    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    Severity   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

}

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName       namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"IncidentGetList"]) {

    [IncidentGetList setObject:Severity forKey:@"Severity"];

     [feeds addObject:[IncidentGetList copy]];
}

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

  if ([element isEqualToString:@"Severity"]) {
      [Severity appendString:string];
   } 


}



- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

NSLog(@"Final Feed : %@",feeds);




 }
```

Comment: Can You answer base on my codes but not showing me your codes and expect me to understand your codes. because i couldn't understand mind either. thats why i am asking here. thank you so much!

Comment: I edit my method For your Xml Parser and Also Don't Forgot to Init Feed in View DIdload   feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: Where did you declare the element attribute?

Comment: i am able to see the data from the log. but was unable to display in my tableView. Please help.

Comment: my code above has the tableview name in .h file call datalist. how to display the array into my table view?

Comment: change Variable Output To feed and `cell.textLabel.text= [[feed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Severity"];`

Comment: and Dont Forgot to reload table in  `parserDidEndDocument`

Comment: If This Answer help you so you can vote up and accept the answer

Comment: I still cannot display the feed array out .. above is the codes i edited on .m. Please take a look and see how can it be solved.

Comment: great answer by you i appreciate your answer